# Application Icon transparency issue (Windows Phone 7)

Tags: windows-phone-7

I'm writing a Windows Phone 7 app and have a icon (both tile icon and app icon).  The icon has my little logo in the middle surrounded by a transparent background.  But when I see the icons on the phone emulator the background is black.  It stays black regardless of what theme is chosen (light or dark).

I would expect that the transparent background would've been filled in with the users chosen Accent Color like all the other icons on the phone (ie, settings etc) but this is not the case.

Do I have to do anything special to have a transparent background?  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My understanding is it was supposed to have been changed to work the way you expect, but for the moment it's only working for 1st party apps. My understanding is this is a bug. A timeframe hasn't been offered for resolution to my knowledge.

Comment: Thanks for the info Mick, I guess that's good news.  Curious, where did you get that info from?  Is there a link you can point me to?

Comment: The larger tile does pick up the accent colour fine as I use this but have the same issue with the smaller application list version where the background is black, I disagree this is a bug but so that first party apps and third party apps can be differentiated - however it could also be an oversight by the UX team and they are supposed to inherit the accent colour!

Comment: I'm not seeing the transparency in the tile, can you share how you got yours to work?

Comment: The bug is mentioned at the bottom of this article: http://expression.microsoft.com/en-us/gg317447.aspx